# ADB Push not keeping file permissions, specifically execute permission

Tags: adb

I "inadvertently" wiped system on my tablet with adb. No critique needed. I've already called myself all the names. What I need now is a way to put at least the "sh" program back on using adb or other program with “x” permission so that I can adb shell once again. Currently, adb removes the “x” permission when using the push option. I examined the adb source code and found one line in the sync section that seems to change permissions to 644. This is a project/challenge to recover this brick. I already have a replacement. Any solutions are welcome. Motherhood comments are not necessary please. Thanks.

P.S. The recovery mode is not working on this tablet (i.e. pwr/vol+/vol-, fastboot, etc.).

Comment: Just wondering: How did you wipe `/system` without recovery? And how do you access the device now without a working recovery? As you wiped `/system`, the device wouldn't boot up into normal mode either.

Comment: Assuming you're on Android 4+, `sh` is symlinked to `mksh`. So why not just `adb shell ln -s /system/bin/mksh /system/bin/sh`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install *Busybox*, *SSHelper* and *Android Terminal Emulator* (ATE). Then try to SSH into your device, if `adb shell` doesn't work. Google for SSH options how to specify the shell to run with remote SSH login. Probably something like `ssh user@ip /system/bin/sh` or try with `... /system/xbin/ash`. Or in ATE you can specify under settings, the shell to use.